# Aleatoric uncertainty in Gaussian Processes

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process, uncertainty

I'm pretty new to statistics and machine learning and I'm studying and implementing GPs. One thing I observed in my studies is that in the figures representing all possible functions given the training points, that there's no variance at the training points. If there is inherent observation noise in training data, why is there no variance at the training points for a Gaussian Process? Should there be? If so, how could we incorporate this?

Answer (score 1):

The GP typically represents the mean value, which should be deterministic (c.f. a regression line has no "wobble"). You can add a "nugget" term to account for noise in observed data. In this case the covariance is modified to become $$C(x,x') = K(x,x') + \lambda^2 \times I(x == x')$$

Here, $K(x,x')$ is any appropriate covariance function (matern, squared exp,...) and $\lambda$ is the standard deviation of the noise - your aleatory uncertainty. $I(X)$ is an indicator function which is $1$ when $X=TRUE$ and $0$ otherwise. This means you add a diagonal term to the data covariance matrix to account for noise.

Comment: You can also have different standard deviations for different data points